# How Ruby on Rails run script file without interact?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run script file, backyard of application. When server started, the script must be run; until server stop. 
I know `rails runner` command; but my script contain database process(insert), and return error named:

```
: uninitialized constant DataRecord (NameError)
```

script.rb :

```
# 
# Some codes here
#

DataRecord.create(sensor_id: data[0].to_s, temperature: data[1].to_f, humudity: data[2].to_f)

# 
# And some codes here..
#

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

DataRecord is my model. It can run on 'application_controller', of course with interaction. Someone must enter the website. I don't want it.

data_record.rb :

```
class DataRecord < ApplicationRecord
end
```

application_record.rb:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
self.abstract_class = true
end
```

activerecord gem is installed.

```
~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112

~$ rails -v 
Rails 5.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `require './config/environment'` at the beginning of your script to load your rails app (and the models you need) in your script.

You might want to make it into [rake](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) or [thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki/Getting-Started) task instead.

Comment: What about ActiveJobs do you think? I don't know how it use. But according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_job_basics.html , it can run backend process; like as i want. However, i have no idea how use it, and i can't understand clearly :/

Comment: To use activejob you need to set up a job runner like sidekiq or resque (if you dont it just runs in your web app process in a thread)

Comment: Ok, friend. I'll try both of  your suggession and activejob, and return result. Thanks.